# Why does Linux report the following as a binary file?

Tags: linux

The file is here

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12337149/history.csv

It views just fine in Notepad but Centos complains about the following

"history.csv" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?

If I choose yes the contents are not properly displayed

Comment: What program/text editor are you trying to open the file in? [I would normally add this as a comment, but I do not have enough reputation to be able to comment on serverfault specifically]

Comment: http://www.thelinuxblog.com/working-with-csv-files-in-bash/

Answer (score 5):

What are you trying to do in Centos that is complaining?  Just looking at the file, the only thing that stands out to me is the UTF-16 Byte Order Mark.  I'd guess that whatever is opening the file  is not dealing w/ the character set correctly and instead thinks it is a binary format.

I have come to this conclusion by doing:
`file history.csv` and getting

> history.csv: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF, CR line terminators

In the shell, when I cat the file I get

> ��Type    Summary Date    Ref Description Period  Opening Ccy Size    Closing Amount
>   WITH  Commissions 14/04/11    4553585 Aurelian
>   Oil & Gas Plc COMM
>   G42H4S    "-" -   �   -   0   -10.16

Then I looked at the hex values of the unknown characters (assuming that shows above) and saw:

> 0000000: fffe 5400 7900 7000 6500 0900 5300 7500  ..T.y.p.e...S.u.

Looking at the [UTF-16 entry on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2), It says that is the Byte order mark, showing the endienness.

So it was a very long path to get to "don't know...maybe it's not dealing with the character set" :)

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem in my case. Running `iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 file.csv > converted.csv` afterwards fixed `less` display.